# NetBeans change "create method" hint behaviour

Tags: netbeans

Suppose I have this code in Java in NetBeans

```
public class Clazz {

    public void method1() {
        method3(); // here is my cursor
    }

    public void method2() {

    }

}
```

So I hit Alt+Enter for hint "create method" which creates my method at the end of class.

```
public class Clazz {

    public void method1() {
        method3();
    }

    public void method2() {

    }

    private void method3() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "Not supported yet." );
    }

}
```

So **my question is how to make method creation just under the current method?** Just like that:

```
public class Clazz {

    public void method1() {
        method3();
    }

    private void method3() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "Not supported yet." );
    }

    public void method2() {

    }

}
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. An earlier [bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=134648) about the placement of code generated by this feature was dismissed:

> The method position is not easy to correct and changes would be possibly inconsistent with other generation behaviour -- currently, we insert the method 
>   at the end of block of class members with same priority (GeneratorUtilities ClassMemberComparator).